# Zip the doc file in ios and save in to document directory

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsdocumentdirectory

I would like to save a doc file into a zip file in the document directory and when the user chooses they can attach it in an email. I have created the zip file but when I want to open it again it creates a zipfile,  `zip.cpgz` instead of `testing.zip` .

Here is my code for creating the zip file

```
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];

NSArray *filePathsArray = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] subpathsOfDirectoryAtPath:documentsDirectory  error:nil];

int index =0;
for (NSString *item in filePathsArray){
    if ([[item pathExtension] isEqualToString:@"doc"])
    {
       NSString *filePath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:[filePathsArray objectAtIndex:index]];
        //NSString *FileName=[stringPath1 stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Console.doc"];

        NSString *stringPath=[documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:[@"testing" stringByAppendingFormat:@".zip"]];

        ZipFile *zipFile = [[ZipFile alloc]initWithFileName:stringPath mode:ZipFileModeCreate];


        ZipWriteStream *stream= [zipFile writeFileInZipWithName:@"doc" compressionLevel:ZipCompressionLevelBest];
        NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:filePath];
        [stream writeData:data];
        [stream finishedWriting];

    }
}
```

Comment: It's not clear what you want.  Please reword it.

Comment: actually i want to compress a doc file and save in to do document directory

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must use [ssziparchive](https://github.com/samsoffes/ssziparchive)

An Utility class for zipping and unzipping files for iOS

Example provided:-

```
// Unzipping
NSString *zipPath = @"path_to_your_zip_file";
NSString *destinationPath = @"path_to_the_folder_where_you_want_it_unzipped";
[SSZipArchive unzipFileAtPath:zipPath toDestination:destinationPath];


    // Zipping
    NSString *zippedPath = @"path_where_you_want_the_file_created";
    NSArray *inputPaths = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
                           [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"photo1" ofType:@"jpg"],
                           [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"photo2" ofType:@"jpg"]
                           nil];
    [SSZipArchive createZipFileAtPath:zippedPath withFilesAtPaths:inputPaths];
```

Comment: This does not answer the question; the issue is not the zip class but the OP's use of the `NSFileManager` class.

Comment: Sorry mate, You are not getting the point what OP is asking , he said has already found a way to zip a file but not find how unzip or extract it . Please read thoroughly before you speak. Simply down voting the answer will just deduct "-1" from your reputation only.

Comment: I did not downvote your answer.  And I'm not your mate.

Comment: I'm guessing you're being downvoted for providing a link-only answer.

Comment: Thanks mate! No matter how much it is down-voted   at-least someone will obviously find it helpful.  @Dan